# Does jQuery autocomplete work with a dynamic array as source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am currently trying to create an autocomplete with a source that is stored in a javascript variable but this variable can be updated by another function. So, what I would like is that at each time the user updates the autocomplete field, the `source` field of autocomplete is generated.

Here is the code I use:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var availableTags = ['java', 'javascript']
        // can be called anytime
        var addToTags = function(str){availableTags.push(str)}

        $(function() {
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Do I need to do a callback-like function?

Comment: You should use $(document).ready().

Comment: What is `sources`? And: does it work currently or not?

Comment: It depends on the autocomplete script you use. some one them has an option that will cache the result. in you case you should set that cache option to `false`.

Comment: I think your source needs to be a function, rather than an array. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: @Bergi $(function (){}) is same as $(document).ready(function(){}) ?

Comment: @HristoYankov It can be an array according to same doc

Comment: Yes, but if your array is changing depending on an another function, it doesn't make sense any more to have an array source.

Comment: @Bergi I corrected the code in the question that line should be `var addToTags = function(str){availableTags.push(str)}`. you can pair review it.

Comment: @habeebperwad: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @ArashMilani Thanks a lot for the edit, it is exactly what I wanted (copy-paste error).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> a source that is stored in a javascript variable but this variable can be updated by another function.

That should just work. If both the autocomplete and the updating function reference the same array, you can push new values at any time which will be used as soon as the array is evaluated next time (e.g. on keystroke).

> I would like that at each time the user updates the autocomplete field, the source field of autocomplete is generated.

That's a different one. Yes, this needs a callback function to generate the `source` array dynamically, but that's simple. Have a look at [the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, resolve) {
        // fetch new values with request.term
        resolve(availableTags);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a reset call to auto-complete in you `addToTags` function:

```
var addToTags = function(str){
   availableTags.push(str);
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
   });
}
```

Comment: I might've mentioned this in my own answer, but I was quite sure that this does not work seamlessly when the autocomplete is currently active. Does it?

Comment: that is why I addded the `destroy` statement. This code is equivalent to calling `autocomplete` on the first time

Comment: Yes, it does destroy the currently open suggestions. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/HBtsF/ and try to use autocomplete there!

Comment: Following your comment I've removed the destroy call and tried to push items to the array on each interval. It worked. I've edited my answer accordingly. check it out yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/HBtsF/1/

Comment: This answer is nice but I would prefer to manage the autocomplete independently of side effect methods.

Answer (score 1):

this is very straight forward

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete('option', 'source', availableTags)
```

setting availableTags array wherever needed

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what solved running within a Google App Script and google.script.run.