# Laravel jQuery Problem that is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, laravel-blade

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.menufocus (jquery-ui.js:5911:50)
    at HTMLUListElement.handlerProxy (jquery-ui.js:626:7)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.js:5430:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery-3.6.0.js:5234:28)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.6.0.js:8719:12)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.js:8797:17)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.0.js:385:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.6.0.js:207:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.6.0.js:8796:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._trigger (jquery-ui.js:715:16)
```

'My Code in blade view is below:'

```
<script>

$( "#searchName" ).autocomplete({
    source: "{{ route('item.autoSrchItem') }}",
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    Select: function(e, ui){
    console.log(ui.item);
  }
});
</script>
```

`My Code in Controller is as:`

```
public function autoSrchItem(Request $request)
{
   $search = $request->term;
   $result = Item::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $search. '%')->get();
   $data = [];
       foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $data [] = ['id'=>$value->id, 'title'=>$value->title];
   } 
      return response()->json($data);
 }
```

`

'Image of my browser:'
[image]

Any one help me please.
I do not understand what the problem is. I am new in Laravel. When i give source a manual data. it works perfectly but when even I give source to my data table it shows the above mansion error.

Comment: I think it's helpful to compare the manual data(that works) vs the data that is queried from db. Usually you should be able to spot the difference and fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery autocomplete documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) `source` should be an `array`.

Route method `route('item.autoSrchItem')` will display something like this `...youwebsite/autoSrchItem` which is just the URL path and that is the `string` which will be displayed into `source`

In your case you need to change code to call method, and not display the URL path `source: "{{ \PathToController\YourController::autoSrchItem() }}",` and in your controller make this method to be `static`

This is example of the JS code:

```
<script>
$( "#searchName" ).autocomplete({
    source: "{{ \PathToController\YourController::autoSrchItem("search_param") }}",
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    Select: function(e, ui){
    console.log(ui.item);
  }
});
</script>
```

And for controller:

```
public static function autoSrchItem($search_param)
{
   $result = Item::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $search_param . '%')->get();
   $data = [];
   ...
```

And this is approach for static autocomplete list, if you want it to be dynamic, according to typed letters, you need to change the logic of your code, and for that maybe this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856429/does-jquery-autocomplete-work-with-a-dynamic-array-as-source) will be the solution